# Spotify Account on Iphone

Tags: iphone, itunes, itunes-store, apple-store, spotify

Can i use my normal (on the website created) Spotify Premium Account on the iPhone or do I have to purchase Premium on iTunes/the Appstore ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Spotify premium account on the iPhone, and you should.
At least where I live (Chile) you save approx 40% on the monthly subscription by buying it directly with Spotify instead of an in-app purchase.

Comment: Thank you :) I was concerned if there is a difference between an online created Account and an in-App created Account. But i didn´t know that my Online Account is cheaper than the in-App Account